# C: Pass two comma separated values with a single #define

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, avr

## The Problem

Programming re-usable modules for microcontrollers (AVR in my case) requires flexibility in general IO pins. Each pin defined by a letter (A-G) and a number (0-7).  It is, however, controlled by one bit at the same positon in three registers. Thus the configuration file needs to contain four entries (3 pointer to the registers + 1 position), which is not that elegant.

The easy fix is to simply accept this, but since it is such a common problem it deserves at least a little attention.

## The Idea

It would be nice to let the precompiler do the repetitive work like this:

```
//CONFIGURATION
#define IO_NAME B5

//MACRO
#define PORT_(ID)
#define PIN_(ID)
#define DDR_(ID)
#define BIT_(ID)
```

The results should look like this

```
PORT_(IO_NAME)   =>  PORTB
PIN_(IO_NAME)    =>  PINB
DDR_(IO_NAME)    =>  DDRB
BIT_(IO_NAME)    =>  5
```

The resulting expressions are defined in AVR Studio.

## What I've Tried

I couldn't figure out how to ignore either the letter not the number, so I tried concatention instead:

```
#define PORT_(REG, BIT)             PORT_2(REG, BIT)
#define PIN_(REG, BIT)              PIN_2(REG, BIT)
#define DDR_(REG, BIT)              DDR_2(REG, BIT)

#define PORT_2(REG, BIT)            (PORT ## REG)
#define PIN_2(REG, BIT)             (PIN ## REG)
#define DDR_2(REG, BIT)             (DDR ## REG)

#define BIT(REG, BIT)               (BIT)
```

The extra layer is required to use any #defined value as either REG or BIT.

The following code works as intended:

```
#define IO_NAME_REG B
#define IO_NAME_BIT 5

PORT_(B, 5)                           => PORTB
PORT_(IO_NAME_REG, IO_NAME_BIT)       => PORTB
```

When I however try

```
#define IO_NAME B, 5
PORT_(IO_NAME)
```

it results in the Error:

```
macro "PORT_" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
```

As far as I figured out the comma is interpreted as the comma operator and thus the left value is ignored. I concluded this from this experiment:

```
#define IO_NAME B, 5
PORT_(IO_NAME,)                      => PORT_5
```

Replacing the comma with a define:

```
#define comma ,
#define IO_NAME B comma 5
PORT_(IO_NAME,)                      => PORT_5
```

leads to the same result

## Workaround

Of course it is possible to seperate the 'B' and '5' into two seperate defines. While this is an improvment over four defines it's still not that comfortable.

## The Question

... is not stricly limited to the title. Any solution which is shorter or simpler than

```
#define IO_NAME_REG B
#define IO_NAME_BIT 5
PORT_(IO_NAME_REG, IO_NAME_BIT)       => PORTB
```

is welcome to me.

If this is simply not possible I'd like to know the reasons why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IO_NAME B, 5

#define PORT_(arg)  PORT_2(arg)
#define PIN_(arg)   PIN_2(arg)
#define DDR_(arg)   DDR_2(arg)
#define BIT_(arg)   BIT_2(arg)

#define PORT_2(reg, bit)    (PORT ## reg)
#define PIN_2(reg, bit)     (PIN ## reg)
#define DDR_2(reg, bit)     (DDR ## reg)
#define BIT_2(reg, bit)     (bit)

#define PORTB   1
#define PINB    2
#define DDRB    3

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", PORT_(IO_NAME));
    printf("%d\n", PIN_(IO_NAME));
    printf("%d\n", DDR_(IO_NAME));
    printf("%d\n", BIT_(IO_NAME));

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
1
2
3
5
```

The `##` in the macro bodies causes the preprocessor to create new tokens by concatenating the operands.

This is almost what you had.  The difference is your top-level macros need to take a single argument, while the secondary macros take two.

Comment: Does not work when you want to specify them by hand, like `PORT_(B, 5)`.

Comment: @Leandros Unless I misread OP's post, that wasn't a goal.  But if it were, then the secondary macros could be used.

Comment: The question has a lot of space for interpretation, that's true.

Comment: Perfect answer! The modified code compiled and runs flawlessly on the chip. ´PORT_(B, 5)´ doesn't need to work as hardcoding is just as simple. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use variadic argument macros instead, with just change you can achieve your goal.

```
#define PORT_(...)             PORT_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PIN_(...)              PIN_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DDR_(...)              DDR_2(__VA_ARGS__)
```